# How to exclude items in your DynamoDB GSI

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

So I am reading about Sparse Indexes, which exclude items based on an attribute being present or not. I am trying to do this in my cloudformation script, with the attributes: `isTenant`. If that attribute is present I want the item to appear in my GSI, if the attribute doesn't exist I don't want it there, this is my table:

```yaml
FooBar:
  Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
  Properties:
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    TableName: FooBarTable

    AttributeDefinitions:
      -
        AttributeName: "pk"
        AttributeType: "S"
      -
        AttributeName: "sort"
        AttributeType: "S"
      -
        AttributeName: "runningFiles"
        AttributeType: "N"


    KeySchema:
      -
        AttributeName: "pk"
        KeyType: "HASH"
      -
        AttributeName: "sort"
        KeyType: "RANGE"

    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
      -
        IndexName: RunningJobsPerTenant
        Projection:
          ProjectionType:
            INCLUDE
          NonKeyAttributes:
            - "isTenant"
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: "pk"
            KeyType: "HASH"
          -
            AttributeName: "runningFiles"
            KeyType: "RANGE"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For any item in a table, DynamoDB writes a corresponding index entry
>   only if the index sort key value is present in the item. If the sort
>   key doesn't appear in every table item, the index is said to be
>   sparse.

Based on above statement from AWS DynamoDB documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html

You would need `isTenant` attribute to be the sort key, so index only is filled when this attribute is present.

The problem you may face now is what to do with your `runningFiles` attribute (in case you need it to query the index). 
My proposal is to overload another attribute, for example:

- Create a new overloaded attribute composed of `pk#runningFiles`
- Create a new attribute which is only present when `isTenant` is true. For example, `runningFilesIfTenant` so you create index using it as sort key and getting same result.

Comment: I see must be in the sort key! Annoying but makes sense.